# How can I copy response target endpoint response payload in a service callout policy with apigee?

Tags: apigee

I need to use the target endpoint response payload as the request payload in a subsequent service callout policy with apigee to be able to log the response using a 3rd party service.

I have tried using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Create-New-Message">
    <DisplayName>Create New Message</DisplayName>
    <AssignTo createNew="true" type="request">newrequest</AssignTo>
    <Copy source='response'>
      <Payload>{response.content}</Payload>
    </Copy>
    <Set>
        <Verb>POST</Verb>
    </Set>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</AssignMessage>
```

But the payload remains empty.

Comment: Fairly certain you need to reference the name of the service callout policy as a prefix like `myServiceCallout.response.content`

Comment: The service callout is after the assign message in the response flow so would itself be using the assign message updated payload. So would be something like: `<Request clearPayload="false" variable="newrequest">
        <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    </Request>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuately I don't have enough reputation points to respond to the previous comment - apologies...

You should look at using the ServiceCallout policy to set all of your request parameters, rather than using AssignMessage + ServiceCallout.  http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/service-callout-policy#request explains how this is done, but the gist is that you would code your verb, headers, etc. as part of the  in ServiceCallout.